# Phaser Controls

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, phaser

In star trek, how does the crew change different  attributes with only two buttons. In the films and series, they change: intensity, width, frequency setting, security clerance (authorisation to fire), self-fire (when wesley uses it as a decoy), self-destruct. How can this be when there is only two buttons, also, how is this shown when again, there is only a single stat indicatior bar (strip atop the phaser)

Comment: It's worth noting that my iPhone only has two buttons.  Phasers don't have interactive screens, but "number of buttons" doesn't necessarily relate to "number of controls."

Comment: Sure, I can imagine the buttons being reassigned, but how is that done, through multiple buttons pushing in a sequence?

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know.  Though, in the world of pure speculation, if I were designing phasers, I'd have them tied to the communicators.  Computer hears you say "Set phasers to stun," and then a "confirm?" button lights up.  You hit Confirm, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really made that clear. It seems that those who've been trained on phaser operations have been told how to access the additional features.

The [TNG Technical Manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) has some additional info but no real answers.

[image]

There's also some info on how to cause an explosion (basically, by dickering with the safety interlock).

> As a result of the basic physics required to produce a phaser
> discharge, an undesirable but unavoidable process exists, namely that
> of phaser overload. The accepted methods employed for energy storage,
> flow, control, and discharge allow for an amplified rebounding to
> occur from the storage cell to the prefire chamber, and simultaneously
> back to the storage cell.
>
> While the total energy within the system
> remains the same, the flow pressure is elevated during the rebound, to
> the point where the storage cell cannot reabsorb the energy fast
> enough. The barrier field will be reinforced during this buildup,
> effectively preventing normal discharge through the emitter.

Comment: Thanks, good info, perhaps pressing the two function buttons cycles through options?

Comment: @pioneer - that seems very likely. Setting it to overload, for instance seems to require a non-trivial level of knowledge

Comment: @Pioneer It could also be that they are each similar to a d-pad, which would essentially allow each button to act as four (with pairs being mutually exclusive).